# How do I select the position of a following sibling

Tags: xslt

I need to select the position of a following sibling via XSL.

This is not working:

```
<xsl:variable name="nextAnswerListItemPos" select="following-sibling::*[local-name() = 'AnswerListItem'][position()]" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="nextAnswerListItemPos" select="count(following-sibling::*[local-name() = 'AnswerListItem'][1]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1" />
```